# Returning a string of selected values from a checkbox collection

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, checkbox, view

I am building a C# MVC view that includes a field with a series of 4 checkboxes. I can populate the list with the values and return individual values just fine, so the basics of the form appear to work. Here is how the options get populated on the view:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.QuesOptions.Count; i++)
{
    <div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.QuesOptions[i].Name)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.QuesOptions[i].Checked)
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.QuesOptions[i].Checked, Model.QuesOptions[i].Name)
    </div>
}
```

The ultimate goal is to return a single list of values (ideally comma delimited) of the values of each item checked at at the time of posting. So when the user clicks "submit" on the form, it would be great if a single field on the view model (called "UserAnswer") would populate with a comma delimited string. Is this even possible right on the view model?

I had hopes, probably empty ones, that some variation of this would work:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Ques.UserAnswer, 
    new { Value = Model.QuesOptions.Where(x=>x.Checked).Select(x=>x.Name) })
```

Or would this be a job for some kind of extension method or HTML helper?

Comment: What is wrong with the sample you've shown? Do you get an error?

Comment: @RufusL - It wasn't returning an error, it was just returning nothing, unfortunately. I think the fields were all coming back as null.

Comment: @RufusL Actually, it was returning only an internal reference:  "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Survey.Models.Question2ViewModel,System.String]"

Comment: You could accomplish this with a simple javascript function that loops through your checkboxes to build up a comma-seperated string, and then set the value of a hidden field inside your html form. If you do this on submit, it should do what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid JavaScript and have everything done only within Razor, but after too much searching and fiddling, JS seems the best way to go. So that's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Finding no way to process comma delimited strings within Razor itself (a way may exist, but I haven't found it), I instead opted for JavaScript. The following code inserts comma delimited lists into hidden fields on the view model:

```
    function submitForm() {
    var question2 = "";
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        var trueOrNo = document.getElementById('Quez2Options_' + i + '__Checked').checked;
        if (trueOrNo) {
            question2 += document.querySelector('label[for="Quez2Options_' + i + '__Checked"]').innerHTML + ",";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('Quez2_UserAnswer').value = question2.substring(0, question2.length - 1);

    var val3a = document.getElementById('Quez3a').value;
    var val3b = document.getElementById('Quez3b').value;
    var val3c = document.getElementById('Quez3c').value;
    var question3 = val3a + "," + val3b + "," + val3c;
    document.getElementById('Quez3_UserAnswer').value = question3;
}
```